# How do I tell which Anchor was clicked using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a div with two links:

```
<div id="copyrightFooter">
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2011 MY Company, LLC. All rights reserved. please review our 
        <a  id="privacyPolicy" style="color: #9DB2E7;font-weight:bold" href="#">Privacy Policy</a> and our <a id="terms" style="color: #9DB2E7;font-weight:bold" href="#">Terms of Use</a>
    </p>
</div> <!-- copyrightFooter-->
```

I am currently capturing the clicks on those two links with JQuery:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Load dialog on page load

    // Load dialog on click
    $('#copyrightFooter a ').click(function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
        return false;
    });

});
```

problem is, this code works for BOTH links. I'd like to "switch/case" which ID i've clicked on so that I can modal-dialog a different DIV. Nothing I do works? "alerting" the ID brings back "undefined" or something similar, so switch case doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So `alert(this.id)` alerts `undefined`?

Comment: How are you trying to get the id? $id = $(this).attr('id'); should give you anchor's id.

Comment: @lonesomeday, it think it has to be `$(this)`, you can `self = $(this)`, and then `self.id`...

Comment: @webarto - No, you can use `this.id`... http://jsfiddle.net/FgxvX/2/

Comment: @webarto `self.id` will be undefined. `this.id` will not be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
$('#copyrightFooter a ').click(function (e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    switch(id){
        case "privacyPolicy": 
            ... 
           break;  
        case "terms": 
           ... 
           break;
    }        
    return false;
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#copyrightFooter a ').click(function (e) {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using `this` in the event handler function will give you a reference to the clicked element. For example, to get the `id` of the clicked element you can do:

```
$('#copyrightFooter a ').click(function (e) {
    var clickedID = this.id;
});
```

You could also use jQuery's `$(this).attr("id");`, but there's no need to overuse jQuery when a simple pure JavaScript statement will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Load dialog on page load

    // Load dialog on click
    $('#copyrightFooter a ').click(function (e) {
        if($(this).attr("id") == "privacyPolicy")
        {
            alert("display Modal 1");
        }else  if($(this).attr("id") == "terms"){
          alert("display Modal 2");
        }

        return false;
    });

});
```

Use $(this).attr("id"); to get the id of div you clicked.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/HPsgE/

Comment: this is why the switch was invented :)

Comment: @webarto why use a switch for two options?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#copyrightFooter a').click(function (e) {

    switch($(this).attr('id')){
        case 'privacyPolicy': id = '#basic-modal-content'; break;
        case 'terms': id = '#basic-modal-content'; break;
    }

    $(id).modal();
    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the id like this:

```
$('#copyrightFooter a ').click(function (e) {
    if(this.id=="privacyPolicy"){
        ..
    }
    else{
        ..
    }
});
```